# couldn't find file 'jquery', couldn't find 'foundation'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, zurb-foundation

I'm having troubles with upgrading from an older Rails 3.0 project to the latest Rails 3.2 (Rails 4 is a bit too edgy) and using the asset pipeline as advertised. I've successfully used the asset pipeline in newer projects with gems like foundation, but getting it to work in this older project seems to be hard, repeatingly getting `Sprockets::FileNotFound` errors. The gemfile is correctly featuring all the gems in the asset group.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "~> 3.2.13"

... database gems ...
gem 'nokogiri'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
....
```

Note that I solved a similar error `Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery'` by moving jquery-rails outside the `:assets`-group, but that is not how at least foundation is supposed to work...

Another problem I'm facing (and might be related) is that `rails g foundation:install` doesn't work, even though `bundle install` command lists that the `zurb-foundation` gem (4.0.9) is being used.

I've tried comparing a freshly generated project that works with the foundation assets with my current project but I seem to look over the difference between the upgraded Rails project's configuration but `Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery'` foundation persists.

Note that I've seen solutions suggesting to move files into your project's `vendor`-folders, but that is not the type of solution I'm after. I'd like to take full advantage of the asset pipeline and try to keep my project as clean as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to move the other gems (foundation, jqueryui) out of the assets group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer myself... guess asking the question helped me spotting the differences between the newly created project and the old project better...

In application.rb the Bundler require statement differed from the newly created project:

`Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)` (old) vs. `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))) if defined?(Bundler)` (new)

I guess the difference entails that besides the default groups the asset groups need to be included when the environment is either development or test.